# The unit of vector3.Distance

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm a beginner in Unity3d and I'm trying to measure the distance between two game objects (spheres). For this, I did at first a line and then, I measured the distance between the two objects using Vector3.Dstance(). However, I got a result 6.4 and I'm not sure if this distance that I measured is in meters or which unit hass the result (Vector3.Distance) that I got. I would appreciate your help.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Line : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject gameObject1;
public GameObject gameObject2;

private LineRenderer line;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    line = this.gameObject.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
    line.startWidth = 0.05f;
    line.endWidth = 0.05f;
    //line.SetVertexCount(2);
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    line.SetPosition(0, gameObject1.transform.position);
    line.SetPosition(1, gameObject2.transform.position);
    float distance = Vector3.Distance(gameObject1.transform.position, gameObject2.transform.position);
    Debug.Log(distance);

    //Debug.DrawLine(gameObject1.transform.position, gameObject2.transform.position, Color.red);

}
```

}

Comment: Theoretically, Unity uses meters and kilograms as their main unit but I think it's only crucial when dealing with CAD objects and not with games. You may treat 1 Unity unit as 1 meter in real life but also... ( when dealing with games ) you can treat is as 1 centimeter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are "game units". Units are whatever you choose them to be, it's all relative.

If you want them to be 1 metre, then you make in-game objects which should be 1 metre equal to 1 game unit, and in-game objects which should be 30 cm, equal to 0.3 game units.

Comment: Be aware that the physics engine needs to be adjusted to the same unit scale. Otherwise gravity will behave oddly.